# Как работает Random в Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Читал про Random и Randomize, и всюду говорят о каких то повторениях, если не использовать Randomize, как получить эти повторения? Делал так:

```
N1
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
for I := 0 to 100 do
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Text := Memo1.Lines.Text + IntToStr(Random(100)) + ', ';
end;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('');
end;

N2
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
for I := 0 to 100 do
begin 
  Randomize;
  Memo1.Lines.Text := Memo1.Lines.Text + IntToStr(Random(100)) + ', ';
end;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('');
end;

N3
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Randomize;
end;
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
for I := 0 to 100 do
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Text := Memo1.Lines.Text + IntToStr(Random(100)) + ', ';
end;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('');
end;
```

Повторений не было

Я хочу понять, как это работает, что бы попытаться добиться такого эффекта: делать рандом из 150, что б при 100 генерациях было максимально неравномерное количество символов, а при 1000000 генераций, количество выпадения каждого числа примерно выравнивалось

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Вы хотите узнать про то как работает Рандом в Делфе, или вам нужен способ генерации равномерного распределения?

Comment: Как работает, для чего это уточнение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> и всюду говорят о каких то повторениях

речь там идет не по повторах при генерации чисел, а при повторах при повторах запусках программы.

вот создали вы консольную программу, содержащую следующий код:

```
for I := 0 to 5 do write(random(100), ', ');
```

запустили, получили вывод (пример)

```
 0, 3, 86,20, 27, 67
```

числа в принципе не повторяются.
Запустили еще раз, и вуаля:

```
 0, 3, 86,20, 27, 67
```

опять те же значения.
Поэтому документация говорит:

> To initialize the random number generator, add a single call Randomize
>   or assign a value to the RandSeed variable before making any calls to
>   Random.

что для генерации последовательности используется начальное значение [`randSeed`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.RandSeed), которое можно либо назначить вручную, либо сгенерировать с помощью функции [`randomize()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Randomize).

Comment: так вариант N1 в вопросе, без Randomize, при нажатии на кнопку генерирую 100 чисел, перезапускаю программу совсем другие значения

Comment: ну во-первых VCL, возможно, и так выполняет `randomize` при запуске, а во-вторых так там разница будет, если промежуток между запусками увеличить.

Comment: хотя вообще вряд ли VCL самостоятельно что-то вызывает.

Comment: у меня повторы только если допишу 
  RandSeed := 0; или любое другое значение